# How do I integrate and then calculate an exponential expression, from 0 to infinity?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

What is

$$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}(0.927)^x\, dx$$

How do I integrate and then calculate this?

Comment: Hint $0.927=e^{?}$

Comment: Hint 2, for $k < 0$, what is the $\lim_{b \to \infty} ~\int_0^b e^{(kx)} ~dx ~$?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**

$$\int{a^xdx}=\frac{a^x}{\ln a}+C$$